# How to print array value by variable's value?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
$productDetail['product']['id']='1324652'; 
$variable = "productDetail['product']['id']";
```

how can i print value of "$productDetail['product']['id']" by using "$variable" in php ?

Comment: You mean assign the value of the array element to the `$variable`? That would simply be `$variable= $productDetail['product']['id']; print $variable;`

Comment: Its a same like we use $$ Lke below example **$a = 'name';
$$a = "Paul";
echo $name; 

output is Paul**

Comment: Sorry, your comment doesn't fit to your initial question, could you therefor explain better what you really try to achieve?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to access a nested array key. As far as I know, this cannot work. What is the source of the string in `$variable`? There must be a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

**is not good way,juse give you a reference**

```js
$productDetail['product']['id']='1111';
$productDetail['product']['idd']['id']='2222'; 

$variable = "productDetail['product']['idd']['id']";
$variable_new = parse_variable($variable);

$re = $$variable_new[0];
if( count($variable_new) > 1 ){
    // loop $variable_new to get next data, one by one
 for( $i = 1; $i < count($variable_new); $i++ ){
  $re = $re[$variable_new[$i]];
 }
}
var_dump( $re );exit;

// parse variable to array
function parse_variable($variable){
 // return $variable if there no [
 if( !strpos($variable, '[') ){
  return array(0 => $variable);
 }

 // parse variable to array
 $variables = explode('[', $variable);
 $new_variables = '';
 foreach( $variables as $variable ){
  $variable = str_ireplace("'", '', $variable);
  $variable = str_ireplace("]", '', $variable);
  $new_variables[] = $variable;
 }
 return $new_variables;
}
```

Comment: Thanks suibber, this is perfect what i really want . but string input is dynamic , coming from user input , so how can i make it dynamic like  use may input "productDetail['product']['id']" or just "productDetail['product']" or "productDetail['product']['id']['id']"

Comment: i edited my answer,you can loop the user input to get the data